# How to keep few documents open in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I noted that Windows 8 tends to suspend applications without notification.

For example - I have a Word doc opened in desktop and then open a pdf doc in the apps and then switch to the word - the pdf will disappear (it can be reopened from left upper menu but I lose the position - need to shuffle through the pages again to find where was I).

Is there a way to 'pin' a certain app/program in memory?

Comment: Note that this applies to Windows Store Apps only. Desktop programs should not be doing this. You could work around it by using a Desktop PDF viewer, such as Adobe Reader or Foxit Reader. The question of disabling the auto-close is still a good one; that seems to (stupidly) be optimised for phones and tablets with limited memory, not laptops and desktops with plenty.

Comment: you actually answered my other question (I didn't think of using Open With :) - please put it as an answer and I'll mark it: http://superuser.com/questions/553339/can-i-have-2-pdf-documents-open-in-windows-8